# Reading an XML File using FileInputStream (for Java)?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, fileinputstream

For my project I have to serialize and deserialize a random tree using Java and XStream.  My teacher made the Tree/RandomTree algorithms, so I don't have to worry about that.  What I don't know how to do is this:  I am using FileInputStream to read/write the xml file that I serialized and deserialized, but when I deserialize, I do not know the method used to read the file.  After I read the file I should be able to convert it from XML and then print it out as a string.  Here's what I have so far.  (I imported everything correctly, just didn't add it to my code segment).

```
FileInputStream fin;        
    
try
{
    // Open an input stream
    fin = new FileInputStream ("/Users/Pat/programs/randomtree.xml");

    //I don't know what to put below this, to read FileInpuStream object fin

    String dexml = (String)xstream.fromXML(fin);

    System.out.println(dexml);
        
    // Close our input stream
    fin.close();    
        
    
    System.out.println(dexml);
        
    // Close our input stream
    fin.close();        
}
// Catches any error conditions
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.err.println ("Unable to read from file");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

---

**Edit:**  I figured it out; I don't think I have to print it as a string, I just needed to make a benchmarking framework to time it and such, but thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The `xstream.fromXML()` method will do the reading from the input stream for you.  I think the problem is that you are casting the return value from `xstream.fromXML(fin)` into a String when it should be cast to the type of object you originally serialized (`RandomTree` I assume).  So the code would look like this:

```
RandomTree tree = (RandomTree)xstream.fromXML(fin);
```

EDIT: after clarification in comments, the author's goal is to first read into a String so the XML contents can be printed before deserialization.  With that goal in mind, I recommend taking a look at the IOUtils library mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/is-there-an-alternative-to-this-way-of-read-file-to-a-string-in-java#326413)

Comment: Well, I wanted to be able to print out what I just read (in a string), so that it would print out both the XML and the deserialized version (in String format).  Is that an easy fix?  I would assume so, but when I did what you said, I got GeneralTree@af72d8 (where it was in my memory I guess)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html (I've never worked with XStream before), you need to define your types first.  Casting to String is definitely wrong, you probably want a customized type (depending on what's inside your random XML), then you need to map the XML tags to your members:

e.g.

```
xstream.alias("person", Person.class);
xstream.alias("phonenumber", PhoneNumber.class);
```

meaning that it maps the "person" tag inside your XML to your Person class.

To derserialize, you can do:

```
RandomTree myRandomTree = (RandomTree)xstream.fromXML( xml );
```

Also, you are closing your stream twice, and you probably want to do it in a finally block :)

edit:  Having read your comment above...

Your task involves two steps:

1. Deserialization
2. Serialization

In order to serialize your object, you must deserialize it first from your input file.

To output your Object as String, simply do

```
String xml = xstream.toXML( myRandomTree );
```